# WSO2 API Manager - Scope validation failed

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

There are two resources in published API as you can see below:

[image]

Resource `/servico-vault-nubank/access` does work with token generated through following configuration:

[image]

When I call `/servico-vault/accounts/1`, it returns following error:

```
    <ams:fault
      xmlns:ams="http://wso2.org/apimanager/security">
      <ams:code>900910</ams:code>
      <ams:message>The access token does not allow you to access the requested resource</ams:message>
      <ams:description>User is NOT authorized to access the Resource: /servico-vault/accounts/{userId}. Scope validation failed.</ams:description>
    </ams:fault>
```

Only difference I see here is URL template in second case. Is there any special configuration I have to do for URLs that supports template?

Important: this error happens only when I call through API product. Direct call works.

Update: If I change endpoint from `GET /api/user/{userId}` to `GET /api/user/{userId}/list`, it does work. It seems that if URL variable is the last part of URI, something goes wrong.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: As per the screenshot from resources page, it seems you have not attached a scope to any of the two api resources. Please confirm. this error can occur when the invoked api resource is protected by a scope and the token used to invoke the resource does not have the scope.

Comment: But there is no scope at all. Actually, if I call API out of API product, it does work. I believe there is something wrong on URL template, may be a product BUG.

Comment: Additionally, POST resource (second one) does work in both cases, inside and outside of API Product.

Comment: Did you update the scope after creating the API product?

Comment: Actually there is no scope...

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems there is no elegant solution to this. I had to delete API Product and recreate. Now it works.

I opened a bug report in WSO2-AM official github.

https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/issues/9766

Please let me know if someone has better solution to this issue.